# Plot theoretical and empirical ACF in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I want to plot theoretical ACF of my model ARMA and empirical ACF of my data in the same chart. I want to get something like in the photo. How can I do that?
 [image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is potentially an interesting and non-trivial question, but we need some more information. Can you show us what you've tried so far, and please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I think some of the machinery in the `nlme` package can compute theoretical ACFs.  But we need more info ...

Comment: I have some data and I fit model ARMA to them. Now I want to compare ACF of model and ACF of data in the same chart. I know how to plot this separately but I don't have idea how to join it. Here my seperate plots.
http://imgur.com/a/vRHj6